# How to handle time out of sync between servers

Tags: java, networking, design-patterns, time

I'm curious if anyone has a best practice or suggestion for my situation:

- a server on which I do not have any influence over offers data via REST.
- The data is only valid for a specific timeframe and gets regularly refreshed.
- The time when the next refresh happens is known via a http headerfield. In the header there is also the current time of the server.
- the time on the server is **off** a few seconds (seems that is is not sync'ed via NTP)

my task is the following:

- grab the new data as short as possible after its refreshed by the server

my question is:

- should I just save the offset-seconds between my servers time and the target server per request and adjust my next pull accordingly?
- should I create some kind of "otherserver"-clock which is regularly synchronized to the clock of the other server and has its offset to trigger my next pull?

What my question is not about: handling of time/timezone.

Best solution would enable me to grab the data right after its update from the other server.

Best Wishes,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other server has a different time than yours then I don't think you should try to "synchronize" to your time by using offsets etc. It might work but knowing that you don't have the proper synchronization it won't be reliable (the time difference might change any time).

If the third party REST server provides you with the current their time and the time of their next data refresh (also in their server time) then you can calculate when the request should be in time measure that doesn't take in account your server time. For example if their current time is 12:00:07 and the next refresh is 12:00:10 then you know you should do the next request after 3 seconds. Just schedule it to your previous request according to the expected refresh time.

Basically you don't care about their time. It can be in some strange timezone or in some strange time unit but whatever it is they tell you how many seconds from your last request you should do your next.